# Struct isn't storing the correct pointer that is passed to it

Tags: c, linux, pointers, struct

I am trying to work on an assignment that has us creating our own malloc function in C, but am having issues with some of these blocks. Essentially my code works with a heap that has blocks added to it as needed. If I add and occupy these blocks in order I have no issues, but I am currently having an issue when I find a block in the middle of this heap and split it to only occupy the needed space. Essentially this block is split and the first portion is occupied, while the second portion is allocated as a free block. Because every block is a doubly linked chain in a list it is aware of the blocks before and after it. For some reason the new block is having troubles pulling values from the original block it stems from. An example output is shown below:

```
Allocating: 3000 bytes
Finding a block...
Iter: 0, Block: 19931136, Size: 5000, Usage: 1
Iter: 1, Block: -767770784, Size: 4500, Usage: 1
Iter: 2, Block: -767766240, Size: 4000, Usage: 1
Iter: 3, Block: -767762208, Size: 2920, Usage: 0
Iter: 4, Block: 19947676, Size: 3500, Usage: 1
Iter: 5, Block: -767775280, Size: 16000, Usage: 0
Splitting a block... (b->nb = 0)
********************************************************
Memory allocation policy: first fit
Total number of bytes allocated: 20200
Total free space in bytes: 15880
Largest contiguous free space in bytes: 12960
Total number of heap extensions: 2
********************************************************
Allocating: 2500 bytes
Finding a block...
Iter: 0, Block: 19931136, Size: 5000, Usage: 1
Iter: 1, Block: -767770784, Size: 4500, Usage: 1
Iter: 2, Block: -767766240, Size: 4000, Usage: 1
Iter: 3, Block: -767762208, Size: 2920, Usage: 0
Splitting a block... (b->nb = 19947676)
********************************************************
Memory allocation policy: first fit
Total number of bytes allocated: 22740
Total free space in bytes: 13340
Largest contiguous free space in bytes: 12960
Total number of heap extensions: 2
********************************************************
Allocating: 2000 bytes
Finding a block...
Iter: 0, Block: 19931136, Size: 5000, Usage: 1
Iter: 1, Block: -767770784, Size: 4500, Usage: 1
Iter: 2, Block: -767766240, Size: 4000, Usage: 1
Iter: 3, Block: -767762208, Size: 2500, Usage: 1
Iter: 4, Block: -767759664, Size: 0, Usage: 0
Iter: 5, Block: -1006104535, Size: -2390907, Usage: -84361856
Segmentation fault
```

I added the iteration printing to show the stages the code goes through when it is using a first fit policy search through the linked list. "Block:" shows the given address of that block in memory. The b->nb following "splitting a block..." shows the actual value of the next block's address as pulled off of the original un-split block before it is split. If you look closely at iteration 5 before the segmentation fault, you can see that the block address is "-1006104535" when it should be "19947676".

So for some reason my code is having trouble copying this pointer when I manipulate blocks in the middle of the list. For more insight I am providing the block_t struct and the split block method, which is clearly where the issue lies after large amounts of debugging.

```
typedef struct block_t{
    int usage;              // Is block free or in use
    size_t size;            // Size of block
    void *previousBlock;    // Ptr to last block
    void *nextBlock;        // Ptr to next block
    char data[1];           // Data space of block

} block_t;
```

...

```
// Function for splitting block into free and used block
void splitBlock(block_t* block, int size){

    block_t* newBlock;

    char *str[80];
    char buffer[(int)block->size - size];

    newBlock = (block_t*) buffer;

 sprintf(str, "Splitting a block... (b->nb = %d)", (int*) block-  >nextBlock);
    puts(str);

    // Intialize new block
    newBlock->usage = 0;
    newBlock->size = block->size - (size_t) size; 
    newBlock->previousBlock = (void*) block;
    newBlock->nextBlock = block->nextBlock;

    // Edit old block
    block->nextBlock = (void*) newBlock;

    totalNumBytesAllocated += size;
    totalFreeSpace -= size;
    totalNumBlocks++;

    return;

} // End splitBlock
```

Any help I could get to help me discover what the issue is would be much appreciated. I feel like the logic is sound, but there might be something I am not understanding in regards to the pointers I am using or the heap I am manipulating. It should be noted that I understand the seg fault issue is because my search is looking for the next block at an obscure location, so I know that this is a pointer issue and that once it is solved, the seg fault will not occur.

Comment: Your function leaks a pointer to an object with automatic storage duration. Use of this pointer after the function returns is undefined behavior.

Comment: This isn't Java. Those automatic objects stop existing when the return is reached. Find the person who taught you to use a char array as generic memory and tell him this is not correct.

Comment: So what is the fix to this? If I'm not using that char buffer to allocate space for the object, what should I use? I definitely can't use malloc, as that would be against the rules and purpose of the assignment.

Comment: I doubt you are actually forbidden from using malloc. You need to use it to allocate a large block of memory, but that memory must be distributed using your own functions, and not malloc.

Comment: Haha no, the point of the assignment is literally to make malloc and we are prohibited from using it. It wouldn't be fair to use a malloc call within a class that is supposed to be a custom malloc.

Comment: Avoid using `char data[1];`  , it formally causes undefined behaviour to go beyond this array. In ISO C you can use `char data[];` to achieve the intended purpose.

Comment: `char buffer[(int)block->size - size]` is not the way to go here. `char *str[80]` is also a mistake - you should be seeing compiler errors (possibly misspelt as "warning") relating to this.  Always fix all compiler messages before trying to run your code.